# Navigation in Cordova failed for Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, jquery, html, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am working on HTML 5 app in Windows phone with Phonegap (Cordova_WP8_2_8_0).
For navigating pages in AJAX I used code as below:

```
<a href="page2.html?Id='+val.pageId+'">..</a>
```

But while debugging I get error as

```
CordovaBrowser_NavigationFailed :: www/page2.html?Id=3
```

I found the same question in StackOveflow but it has no response.

I don't know how to sort this, any ideas?

FYI: `val.pageId` is dynamic value got through AJAX.

Comment: Found the answer It works fine replace <a href="page2.html?Id='+val.pageId+'">..</a> as <a href="page2.html#Id='+val.pageId+'">..</a>